# Strange Characters instead of actual titles in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse

[image: Snippet of Eclipse]

Strange characters are being shown in different tabs in  Eclipse IDE. I have tried reinstalling and nothing changed.
But when I hover over those tabs it shows the actual name.
The issue seems to be only with the different tabs, rest are fine(menus and project name inside the Workspace explorer)

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, others have encountered this behavior before, but I can't find any solutions on the web or bugs posted to the Eclipse bug base. I probably need more coffee, but maybe you can do better.

Comment: See [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551965). It is something to do with the fonts installed on your system.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you soo much :) . Changing the theme to Classic in appearance fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in no time
In eclipse change manually the font "Segoe UI Symbol" to another font type by navigating to (Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Font > View and Editor Folders > Part title font) Edit... and change font.

Comment: this did the trick! "part title font", one has to know and find.

Comment: @Kleajmp, I'm glad it did.