# The names in the eclipse are buggy, can someone help me?

Tags: java, eclipse

Today I was changing the folders on my desktop, and I ended up changing the name of the folder that contained all of my Programming projects. So far everything was ok, because I thought "just reopen the projects again in the applications". However, when I went to open the project again at eclipse, the names of all the tabs came out buggy. Does anyone know how to solve?

[image: Eclipse Image]

Comment: It is a issue with the fonts installed on your system see [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=551965)

Comment: See also the comments in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970368/strange-characters-instead-of-actual-titles-in-eclipse).

Comment: These articles helped. There was no need to change the windows layout. The problem was in the font "Segoe UI" that I was using, I changed it to Arial it was perfect again @greg-449