# I got strange symbols in Eclipse tabs

Tags: java, eclipse

smth is wrong with my Eclipse and now i have such strange symbols like that, does anyone know how to fix it?

[image: My_eclipse]

Comment: Just kidding, seems like related to a bug caused by some font that you installed. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62970368/strange-characters-instead-of-actual-titles-in-eclipse

Comment: Try changing the Theme to default, that fixed the issue for the link's op